# I got movenext() exception

Tags: c#

```
`enter code here`
```

public override string GetUserNameBySicil(string sicil)
        {
            int total = -1;

```
        var users = FindUsersBySicil(sicil, 0, 3, out total);
        if (total > 0)
        {

            var user = (MemberUser)users.GetEnumerator().Current;


            return user.Sicil;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
          return this._Values.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Movenext

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is the *text* of the exception? is it saying something about collection modified, for example? note: your code *doesn't show* any `MoveNext()` usage, so ... no context to help us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `MoveNext()` you need to keep hold of the iterator and just... call `MoveNext()`, as shown below.

The most common reason that `MoveNext()` would throw an exception is that the collection was modified - you added/removed/replaced an item. That isn't usually allowed, so you'd have to construct your code to *not do that*. Perhaps by tracking *planned* changes when you iterate, then applying them *after* you've iterated.

---

```
var iter = users.GetEnumerator();
using(iter as IDisposable)
{
    while(iter.MoveNext())
    {
        var user = (MemberUser)iter.Current;
        // ...
    }
}
```

which is the same as:

```
foreach(MemberUser user in users) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that ideally you'd have `IEnumerator<MemberUser>`, which would simplify this greatly:

```
using(var iter = users.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(iter.MoveNext())
    {
        var user = iter.Current;
        // ...
    }
}
```

which is the same as:

```
foreach(var user in users) {
    // ...
}
```